# Routing query strings

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing

I have a form in my template file:

```
                {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'get.index', 'method' => 'get')) }}
                    {{ Form::label('order', 'Order by') }}
                    {{ Form::select('order' , array('firstname' => 'First Name', 'lastname' => 'Last Name', 'state' => 'State')) }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Order results') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
```

When submitted, this forms outputs a GET query variable named order, so my URL will be:

```
http://my.app/?order=firstname
```

This is the get.index route:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@index', 'as' => 'get.index'));
```

Is there a simple way to change the URL from the one above to something like 
`http://my.app/order/fistname/` ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can have a route like this is to use a [route parameter](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters):

```
Route::get('/order/{type}', array(
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index', 
    'as' => 'get.index'
));
```

and then you can use the `type` parameter in your controller method:

```
public function index($type) {

}
```

But it will not work with your actual form unless you format the form action value in javascript to fit this route.

But if you can use something else than a form you could easily do it with a HTML `a` tag, for exemple:

```
Order by:
<a href="{{ route('get.index', 'firstname') }}">firstname</a>
<a href="{{ route('get.index', 'lastname') }}">lastname</a>
```